# How do I know what tempX mean in sensors output?

Tags: sensors

The `temp[[:digit:]]` things are confusing. Can the output of `sensors` be more human readable?

```
$ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +59.0°C  (crit = +127.0°C)
temp2:        +60.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)

thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:        2990 RPM
temp1:        +59.0°C  
temp2:        +53.0°C  
temp3:        +41.0°C  
temp4:        +76.0°C  
temp5:        +36.0°C  
temp6:            N/A  
temp7:        +33.0°C  
temp8:            N/A  
temp9:        +43.0°C  
temp10:       +51.0°C  
temp11:       +49.0°C  
temp12:           N/A  
temp13:           N/A  
temp14:           N/A  
temp15:           N/A  
temp16:           N/A
```

---

Now it is like the following. Do they indicate my laptop is healthy? Do I have to worry about that? The reported temperatures are when I am opening 100 tabs in chrome browser now. They are achieved when I use a cooler and scale the cpu frequency to the lowest 0.8GHz. WIhtout a cooler, the highest temperature will be over 80 celcius. If further without cpu freq scaling, the highest can be 90 and 100 celcius.

```
$ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
CPU_0:        +57.0°C  (crit = +127.0°C)
CPU_1:        +56.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)

thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Fan:                                                   2939 RPM
CPU neighbourhood (also via ACPI THM0):                 +57.0°C  
Ultrabay:                                               +51.0°C  
Express card:                                           +38.0°C  
ATI graphics module:                                    +73.0°C  
Main battery (always around 50°C):                     +36.0°C  
n/a (probably ultrabay battery):                            N/A  
Main Battery (fits about the value reported by smapi):  +33.0°C  
n/a (probably ultrabay battery):                            N/A  
Hard disc:                                              +40.0°C  
Intel graphics module:                                  +48.0°C  
Heatsink?:                                              +46.0°C  
n/a:                                                        N/A  
n/a:                                                        N/A  
n/a:                                                        N/A  
n/a:                                                        N/A  
n/a:                                                        N/A
```

Comment: And what output do you expect?

Comment: Describe what and where `tempx` is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you could do this by editing the `/etc/sensors3.conf` file as discussed [here](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/7607/how-to-identify-lm_sensors-output/).

> To have `sensors` use describing labels like above, you can add the
>   following section to **/etc/sensors3.conf**, if not already there. Use the
>   sensor location findings below.

You could add the details as below.

```
chip "thinkpad-isa-0000"   
label fan1   "Fan"   
label temp1  "CPU"  
label temp2  "HDAPS"   
label temp3  "PCMCIA"   
label temp4  "GPU"  
label temp5  "System battery (front left, charging circuit)"   
label temp7  "System battery (rear right)"   
label temp9  "Bus between Northbridge and DRAM; Ethernet chip"   
label temp10 "Southbridge, WLAN and clock generator"   
label temp11 "Power circuitry"
```

You could probably get information about your model from [here](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Thermal_Sensors).

Comment: thanks. my highest temperature is 75 celcius, coming from temp4. temp4 is ATI graphics module. Is it the same as GPU? Why is it so high?

Comment: @Tim, I believe so. GPU is the graphics processing unit and so its possible that graphics is consuming that much.

Comment: @Tim, GPUs are designed to run hot.  It lets them get away with the sort of tiny heatsink you can fit into a standard-height PCI slot.

Comment: @Mark: is gpu designed to endure higher temperature than cpu?

Comment: @Tim, In general, yes.  I don't have numbers for modern parts, but back when I was into overclocking, the "never exceed" temperature for my CPU was 70C, while that for the GPU was 105C.

Comment: How can I find out my GPU critical temperature? @Mark